# Allow manually entered text in ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am using a select box from ui-select. All is working fine, but I want to allow manually entered text and do not want to restrict the user from the values available in the list. If I type in text it filters my list correctly. But when I not click on an element and move on to the next field my text will get discarded.

Any ideas?

Thanks and regards,
Alex

I did not want to show my code because I think it is not correct, but it was requested:

```
<ui-select ng-model="formData[field.id].selected" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{ lists[field.id].placeholder }}">{{$select.selected.text}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in lists[field.id].list | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.text | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The data is stored in `formData[field.id].selected`. `field.id` is the number of the current field to display (I am generating my form dynamically). Just assume that it stores an unique int value.

Edit 08.04.2015
**My solution:**
I found out that it seems as if there is no equivalent to a C# combobox. So I went ahead and used two separate fields. It is not what I wanted, but it works for now:

```
<ui-select ng-model="formData[field.id].selected" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{ lists[field.id].placeholder }}">{{$select.selected.text}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in lists[field.id].list | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.text | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
<?php echo __('Create a new element if value is not in list'); ?>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled[field.id]">
    </span>
    <input type="text" value="" ng-disabled="!disabled[field.id]" class="form-control" ng-model="formData[field.id].newValue" />
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I am not sure why I am being downvoted. It would be enough if someone could point me to some documentation. The ui-select github offers some examples, but none mit editable text.

Comment: Can you share some code aswell ?

Comment: I did not want to share code because I am pretty sure it is not correct. I'll add some if it helps.

Comment: I needed this feature in select2 and scratched my head to make it accept free text but then I realised typeahead is made for this exact case. So if you do not need multiple selection typeahead is what you need.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

here is a solution:

HTML -

```
<ui-select ng-model="superhero.selected">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a superhero ...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="hero in getSuperheroes($select.search) | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind="hero"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

CONTROLLER -

```
$scope.getSuperheroes = function(search) {
 var newSupes = $scope.superheroes.slice();
  if (search && newSupes.indexOf(search) === -1) {
    newSupes.unshift(search);
  }
  return newSupes;
}
```

Here is the [CodePen solution](http://codepen.io/arcotnaresh/pen/bVqqdj).

Answer (score 13):

I think I found a way to allow the user to create new entries. Use the "on-select" attribute to pass a function that takes $select as a parameter as below:

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected"
      theme="select2"
      on-select="peopleSel($select)"
      tagging
      reset-search-input="false"
      >

    <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter a name...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="sel in people | filter: {name: $select.search}">
    <div ng-bind-html="sel.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Then create the function that adds a new entry when the clickTriggeredSelect variable is false:

```
$scope.peopleSel= function(sel) {
  if ( sel.search && ! sel.clickTriggeredSelect ) {
    if ( ! sel.selected || sel.selected.name != sel.search ) {
      //Search for an existing entry for the given name
      var newOne= personSearch( sel.search ); 
      if ( newOne === null ) {
        //Create a new entry since one does not exist
        newOne= { name: sel.search, email: 'none', country: 'unknown' };
        $scope.people.push( newOne );
      }
      //Make the found or created entry the selected one
      sel.selected= newOne;
    }
  }
  sel.search= ''; //optional clearing of search pattern
};
```

Note that personSearch definition is not provided here. Also this approach of testing the clickTriggeredSelect can be used to allow the user to unselect the field if a blank entry is the preference.

PVC

Comment: ui-select v0.19 introduced a new [`uis-open-close` directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/uis-open-close). If you put the function in there instead of in `on-select`, entries will be added even on blur.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the **tagging** attribute as explained in the documentation:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select

```
<ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="(custom 'new' label)" ng-model="multipleDemo.colors">
...
</ui-select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to the wiki. I was searching for documentation or examples but totally missed the wiki. Tagging is not what I need though. Tagging only works when using `multiple`. I want a select which acts like a select and a text input in one item. If your text is already in the list you can click on it, if not your text will be stored.

Comment: @AlexWerz : Have you got the solution ? If so, can you please share it. Thanks.

Comment: No sorry. I used the solution I provided in the edit above. But there is no real equivalent to a C# Combobox. I switched some of my GUIs to angular.js which has some more options and possibilities. Maybe you should have a look at it too.

Comment: As per official sample of `angular-ui` `tagging` does not works with single select. It only works with multiple

Link to [Official Angular UI Github sample](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/docs/examples/demo-tagging.html)

Answer (score 4):

I've forked the ui-select project to allow this functionality through the allow-free-text attribute

```
<ui-select allow-free-text="true" ng-model="ctrl.freeTextDemo.color2" theme="bootstrap" style="width: 800px;" title="Choose a color">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select color...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in ctrl.availableColors | filter: $select.search">
      <div ng-bind-html="color | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here is the [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/htlL73tK30cl8AVXVktt?p=preview)

Until my pull request is accepted by the angular-ui team, you can get the ui-select build that includes my patch on [my own repo](https://github.com/ahocquet/ui-select)

Comment: I love this solution. What's the status/comments of your pull request? Was unable to find it on GitHub.

Comment: Unfortunately, ui-select team rejected my PR, they want to use their tagging system instead. Here's the PR link : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/1659

Comment: Would be better if you made a self contained directive for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use `keyup` to add a new option represents the text entered. With this approach, if user press `enter`, they can select what they have input so far (the default active item is the first item).

This supports both cases when the data list contains plain text or object (attribute `value-prop` is required).

Directive:

```
commonApp.directive("uiSelectFreeText", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "uiSelect",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, $select) {
            var searchInput = element.querySelectorAll("input.ui-select-search");

            if (searchInput.length !== 1) {
                console.log("Error! Input not found.");
                return;
            }

            searchInput.on("keyup", function () {
                var valueProp = attrs["valueProp"];
                var addNewObjOption = function () {
                    // add new item represent free text option
                    var newOption = { isFreeText: true };
                    newOption[valueProp] = $select.search;
                    $select.items.unshift(newOption);
                };

                if ($select.items.length > 0) {
                    var firstItem = $select.items[0];

                    if (valueProp) {
                        // items is list of Object
                        if (firstItem.isFreeText) {
                            firstItem[valueProp] = $select.search;
                        } else {
                            addNewObjOption();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // items is list of string
                        if (firstItem === $select.search) {
                            return;
                        } else {
                            $select.items.push($select.search);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (valueProp) {
                        addNewObjOption();
                    } else {
                        // items is list of string
                        $select.items.push($select.search);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<ui-select class="ui-select-control"
           ui-select-free-text value-prop="Label"
           ng-model="keyword">
</ui-select>
```