# AngularJS ui-select allow to write only number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I have followed by this answer
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489821/allow-manually-entered-text-in-ui-select#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489821/allow-manually-entered-text-in-ui-select#_=_)

But have problems when add `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"` to the `ui-select`, doesn't work anymore. Any workaround?

Have found this on Github, so it haven't fixed yet
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/855

Comment: please put your code here along with the exact error which you are facing.

Comment: what is your angularjs version ?

Comment: AngularJS v1.4.8, and my code looks the same like in link i added, very similar to this http://codepen.io/arcotnaresh/pen/bVqqdj but added only ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" and not work anymore, to ui-select

Answer (score 0):

You could force the input, present in the ui-select, with class "ui-select-search" to be a number type.

Like this example:

```
$("#idUiSelect .ui-select-search").attr('type', 'number').attr("min","0");
```

I've used JQuery for term of time

Comment: I can't see how this is related to the question?